# Monitor system for Akka cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

It's very difficult to keep track of the states of all actors in Akka cluster. I've been searching around the internet for a good system for monitoring Akka cluster system. However, the results were most likely systems to monitor JVM stats. I am curious if there is a system I can use to monitor the statistics below :

1. What are the active actors, their states and all other attributes.. i.e connect time, role, path, host etc
2. The status of all active shard regions and their shards
3. The messages buffered in Akka (Pending messages)
4. The deadletter mailbox
5. The status of the coordinators

Answer (score 0):

You could just have some observing actor send messages to the actors you want to see the state of to tell them to send a message back to this observing actor with a snap shot of their state.

You can use Agents somewhat as well but I don't think they are distrubuted however.

If you were looking for some common framework or something to do this then I would suggest trying to bundle some of this behavior to a trait, I don't really know what that would like that because it depends allot on how you invision this behavior working, if all the messages sent back to the observer can be of the same case class or not, ect.

Answer (score 0):

[`Kamon.io`](http://kamon.io/) can gather matrixes as you want.
for [instance](http://kamon.io/core/metrics/recording-metrics/) :

```
val myHistogram = Kamon.metrics.histogram("my-histogram")
myHistogram.record(42)
myHistogram.record(43)
myHistogram.record(44)

val myCounter = Kamon.metrics.counter("my-counter")
myCounter.increment()
myCounter.increment(17)

val myMMCounter = Kamon.metrics.minMaxCounter("my-mm-counter", refreshInterval = 500 milliseconds)
myMMCounter.increment()
myMMCounter.decrement()

val myTaggedHistogram = Kamon.metrics.histogram("my-tagged-histogram", tags = Map("algorithm" -> "X"))
myTaggedHistogram.record(700L)
myTaggedHistogram.record(800L)
```

Also, [Kamon.io supports several backends](http://kamon.io/backends/log-reporter/) as a datastore of these metrixes.